# Overriding a Swift { get set } property to a { get } only property. Making a variable a constant

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding

Is it possible to override a variable to a constant?
Basically this is the best I could come up with:

```
class TextStyle: UITextLabel {
    private let _textStyle: FontStyle
    override public var textStyle: FontStyle {
        get { return _textStyle }
        set {
            #warning ("you cant set")
            if newValue != _textStyle {
                self.textStyle = _textStyle
            }
        }
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, textStyle: FontStyle) {
        self._textStyle = textStyle
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

If its not possible to override a var to a constant i want user to be notified on compile time that they cant **set** the property. The `#warning` doesn't work, its just the best i could come up with. I believe there is a possible way using protocols to do this, which is more complex. Similar to codable, encodable and decodable.

Comment: What's a `UITextLabel`?

Comment: Its a subclass of UILabel that is themable basically.